# Independent inner functions on the unit disk

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, inner-product

This problem cropped up in a paper that I am writing and I have thought about it for too long to no avail: let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane and suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ is inner ($|\varphi(z)|=1$ a.e. for $z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$) with $\varphi(0)=0$. Can there exist another inner function $\psi:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ such that  $\psi(0)=0$ and $\langle \varphi^n,\psi^m\rangle=0$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$?

Here, $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product on the Hardy space $H^2(\mathbb{D})$,
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\frac 1 {2\pi}\sup_{0\leq r< 1}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta})\overline{g(re^{i\theta})} \ d\theta.
$$

I am aware that independent holomorphic random variables is an area of interest, but I am nowhere near expert enough to see whether the question is a trivial corollary of some result therein.